# JavaFX CSS for all FXML Default Buttons

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I'm using the default button property on all of my Modal Windows.

Which is the CSS property to modify all of them without the need of creating a new CSS class id?

[image]

By default all of them are light-blue with a black font color, and i don't really like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#button), you should be able to use

```css
.button:default {
    /* your style rules here */
}
```

in your external CSS file.

The default stylesheet, modena.css, has the rule

```
.button:default {
    -fx-base: -fx-default-button ;
}
```

where `-fx-default-button` is defined as a light blue:

```css
-fx-default-button: #ABD8ED;
```

so another option would just be to change the definition of `-fx-default-button`:

```css
.root {
    -fx-default-button: /* your preferred color here */ ;
}
```